# Is it possible for a finite group to have two isomorphic subgroups which is maximal and non-maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Is it possible that there exist two subgroups $H$ and $L$ of $G$ such that the following three conditions hold:

1. $H \cong L$
2. $H$ is maximal in $G$
3. $L$ is not maximal in $G$

Any example is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Edit: This problem comes from computing unfactorizable morphisms in transporter category of group $G$. I searched for all subgroup of $S_5$ (See for the [lattice of S5](https://www.mathsjournal.com/pdf/2018/vol3issue2/PartH/3-2-46-714.pdf)) containing a subgroup of order 2 and find out that if the 2-order subgroup is maximal so is all other 2-order subgroup. This is also true for subgroups containing 3-order subgroup. On the other hand, I searched the key world "maximal subgroup" in Dummits AA book, find no useful result to disprove the statement. I Also find no related result on the internet. So I conjecture that the answer is negative. But maybe a big finite group can be an example?

Comment: This seems related and might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616756/maximal-subgroups-and-isomorphism

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes this is possible. There might be smaller examples, but one way to construct them is using *twisted wreath products*. The smallest example of this type is $G=A_5 \wr A_6$.

This has (at least) two conjugacy classes of subgroups isomorphic to $A_6$, one maximal and the other non-maximal.

The natural complement in the wreath product is not maximal in $G$. It normalizes the diagonal subgroup of the base group, resulting in a larger subgroup isomorphic to $A_5 \times A_6$.

However, there is another "twisted" complement of $G$ that is maximal. Roughly speaking, you twist it by making the stabilizer of the first block induce inner automorphisms of the first direct factor $A_5$ of the base group.

In my answer to [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391817), I gave this example as the smallest example of a primitive permutation group of twisted wreath product type inthe O'Nan-Scott Theorem.

$\textbf{Added Later}$. Here is a much smaller example, that you can check more easily on a computer. The Mathieu group $M_{12}$ has two conjugacy classes of subgroups isomorphic to ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$, one maximal, and the other non-maximal (contained in $M_{11}$).

$\textbf{Added Even Later}$. Thanks to MikkoKorhonen for pointing out that this question (asking specifically whether there are solvable examples) has already been discussed at some length in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153433). I see from there that there is a smaller example than $M_{12}$. For a simple group $S$, the group $G = S \times S$ has two different types of subgroups isomorphic to $S$, the component subgroups, which are non-maximal, and the diagonal subgroups, which are maximal. The smallest such example is $A_5 \times A_5$ of order $3600$.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explain how you find such a complicated example? Do you find the example by analyzing the requirement or just some example you already knew fits into the narrative?  Thanks again.

Comment: I knew about the twisted product construction of maximal subgroups already, and I found the $M_{12}$ example by searching theorugh the ATLAS of Finite Groups.

Comment: I wonder what smallest example of this is?

Comment: It is easy to see that there are no examples among nilpotent finite groups. Are there any solvable examples?

Comment: @spin Yes, that's an interesting question!

Comment: Whether there are solvable example seems to be an open question, see question on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153433/subgroups-of-finite-solvable-groups-with-paradoxical-properties).  Some results are in these papers: [MR3348779](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3348779) (I. M. Isaacs, G. R. Robinson) and [MR3955594](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3955594) (G. Glauberman, G. R. Robinson).

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen Thanks for the pointer to the MO article (I see have already commented there, so I should have remembered it!) From there I see also that $A_5 \times A_5$ is a smaller example than $M_{12}$ - I will edit my answer.